# Obtaining List or array of long as a parameter using jax-rs and jersey

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

I use JAX-RS and Jersey. I have method like that. And it doesn't work for me.

```
@POST
public Response addOrder(List<Long> ids) {
    ...
}
```

When I send request using Postman I got an error.

```
Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token 
at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@6befd3c2; line: 1, column: 1]
```

My request:

```
{
"ids": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Is there any ways to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You need a class which contains an attribute `ids`

```
public class IdList {
  private List<Long> ids;

  // getter and setter
}
```

then

```
@POST
public Response addOrder(IdList idList) {
}
```